# ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is 22

Tags: r, conda, blas, openblas

Problem: I created a conda environment in a Docker repository to run a snakemake pipeline. I used the same running conda environment file running on my mac (R 3.6.1). Everything runs smoothly till it gets to the normalisation with MSnbase package where it fails, I get the following error with MSnbaSe library:

```
msnset.nrm <- normalise(data, "quantiles")
Error in preprocessCore::normalize.quantiles(exprs(object), ...) : 
  ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is 22
```

After checking the internet, it seems to be a problem with openblas. 
On my Mac (where it runs perfectly), sessionInfo() shows the following:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /Users/MH/miniconda3/envs/snakemake_all/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib

Random number generation:
RNG:     Mersenne-Twister
Normal:  Inversion
Sample:  Rounding

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

and conda list | grep blas shows:

```
libblas                   3.8.0               12_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               12_openblas    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0               12_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.7                hd44dcd8_1    conda-forge
```

I tried to build the conda in docker using R 3.6.1 and the same blas packages. Unfortunately, linux 0.3.7 libopenblas package (build h6e990d7_0) reproduced the error continuously. Any advice on this matter?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

From this [question](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/122925/) and this [issue](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/16481), I think you can fix it by downgrading `libopenblas` to 0.3.3. So when you create your conda environment you should do something like

```
conda create -n my-env libopenblas=0.3.3 other-packages
```

Now, whether downgrading `libopenblas` will break other things, I've no idea

Answer (score 0):

Two of the working solutions reported for the [same issue on github](https://github.com/Bioconductor/bioconductor_docker/issues/22) require you to disable threading during `preprocessCore` installation.

Way 1 (I install packages through R so prefer this):

```
BiocManager::install("preprocessCore", configure.args = c(preprocessCore = "--disable-threading"), force= TRUE, update=TRUE, type = "source")
```

Way 2 (Manual installation):

```bash
- name: Manually install preprocessCore
        run: |
          git clone https://github.com/bmbolstad/preprocessCore.git
          cd preprocessCore
          R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--disable-threading"  .
```